# Human Character Recognition using Tesseract

Tags: ocr, tesseract

Initially I have tried training the Tesseract Engine for a single font and get an output using that trained dataset. And it worked fine as in the following tutorial.

http://www.resolveradiologic.com/blog/2013/01/15/training-tesseract/

But my requirement is to train the engine for multiple fonts and create a single model. How can I do it?